# HAWQ distribute randomly and disk space for each segment is almost full. add new datanode

Tags: greenplum, hawq

I am reading the specification of HAWQ. There is a question: I create a table (such as 'table_random') with distribute randomly in 3 data-nodes cluster, and disk space for each segment is almost insufficient. Then I add a new data-node to the cluster, then when I insert data to table 'table_random',

```
- Does HAWQ will distribute data to the old data-nodes ? What will happen actually?
- Does HQWQ will redistribute the data of table 'table_random' overall the cluster?
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create tables in HAWQ that are specified with a hash distribution key or randomly.  With HAWQ 2.0, you should use random distribution but first, let's talk about how hash distribution works in HAWQ.

```
create table foo (id int, bar text) distributed by (id);
```

HAWQ has a concept of buckets for hash distributed tables.  Basically, there is a file in hdfs that corresponds to each bucket.  With a partitioned table, there is a file per partition and per bucket but let's just focus on my foo table above.

When you init your database, the GUC default_hash_table_bucket_number gets set.  It is calculated based on the number of nodes * 6.  (Clusters with 85 - 102 nodes is 5 * number of nodes and so on)  So a 10 node cluster will have a default_hash_table_bucket_number=60.  Therefore, there will be 60 files in HDFS for my foo table.

- When you execute a query against foo, there will be 60 virtual segments (one for each file) for that one table.
- When you expand your cluster, the number of buckets for my table is fixed.  60 buckets will still work but it will be spread over all of the nodes.
- After an expansion and using hash distribution, you should adjust default_hash_table_bucket_number based on the number of nodes in the cluster and then recreate hash distributed tables so that it will have the correct number of buckets.

You can also specify the number of buckets for at table like this:

```
create table foo (id int, bar text) with (bucketnum=10) distributed by (id);
```

Now I'm forcing the database to have 10 buckets for my table rather than using the value from default_hash_table_bucket_number.

But randomly distributed tables are recommended over hash.  Why?  Because of elasticity.

```
create table foo_random (id int, bar text) distributed randomly;
```

Now this table will only create a single file in hdfs.  The number of vsegs is determined at runtime based on the query optimizer.  For a small table, the optimizer may only execute a single virtual segment while a very large table may use 6 virtual segments per host.

When you expand your cluster, you will not need to redistribute the data.  The database will automatically increase the total number of virtual segments if needed too.

hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_perseg_limit is the GUC that determines how many possible virtual segments will be created per query per segment.  By default, this is set to 6 but you can increase or decrease it. hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_limit is another GUC that is important here. It defaults to 512 and controls the total number of virtual segments that can execute for a query cluster wide.

So in summary, in HAWQ with Random Distribution:

- Recommended storage technique
- Adding nodes doesn't require redistribution of the data
- Removing nodes doesn't require redistribution of the data
- hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_perseg_limit can be increased from 6 to higher values to increase parallism.
- hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_limit may need to be increased from 512 to a higher value.  It specifies the total number of virtual segments across the entire cluster per query.

Comment: Hi Jon Roberts, thanks very much for your response. I still have a issue : after I expand  my cluster, does HAWQ will write data (cause executing INSERT query ) to data-nodes whose disk space is insufficient ?    thanks

Comment: A HAWQ segment will write to the local data node on INSERT and then HDFS will make copies of that data for redundancy.  If you have one node with insufficient space, you should run hdfs balancer to redistribute the data across the new nodes.  The copies of the data is a function of hdfs, not HAWQ.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much :)